# Kafka Streams: use the same `application.id` to consume from multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application that needs to listen to multiple different topics; each topic has separate logic for how the messages are handled. I had thought to use the same kafka properties for each KafkaStreams instance, but I get an error like the one below.

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Assigned partition my-topic-1 for non-subscribed topic regex pattern; subscription pattern is my-other-topic
```

**Code** (kotlin)

```
class KafkaSetup() {
    companion object {
        private val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)
    }

    fun getProperties(): Properties {
        val properties = Properties()
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-app")
        return properties
    }

    private fun listenOnMyTopic() {
        val kStreamBuilder = KStreamBuilder()
        val kStream: KStream<String, String> = kStreamBuilder.stream("my-topic")

        kStream.foreach { key, value -> LOG.info("do stuff") }

        val kafkaStreams = KafkaStreams(kStreamBuilder, getProperties())
        kafkaStreams.start()
    }

    private fun listenOnMyOtherTopic() {
        val kStreamBuilder = KStreamBuilder()
        val kStream: KStream<String, String> = kStreamBuilder.stream("my-other-topic")

        kStream.foreach { key, value -> LOG.info("do other stuff") }

        val kafkaStreams = KafkaStreams(kStreamBuilder, getProperties())
        kafkaStreams.start()
    }
}
```

I found this [reference](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/confluent-platform/0dUszvmfkyQ/UQO1uwbQCAAJ) that suggest that you can not use `application.id` for multiple topics, however I am finding it hard to find reference documentation to support that. The [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation.html#streamsconfigs) for `application.id` states:

> An identifier for the stream processing application. Must be unique within the Kafka cluster. It is used as 1) the default client-id prefix, 2) the group-id for membership management, 3) the changelog topic prefix.

**Questions**

1. What does this error mean, and what causes it.
2. Given that you can have multiple instance of you app running with the same id to consume from multiple topic partitions, what does *"Must be unique within the Kafka cluster"* mean?
3. Can you use the same Kafka streams `application.id` to start two `KafkaStreams` that are listing on different topics? and if so, how?

***Details:** kafka 0.11.0.2*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Kafka Streams scales via partitions, not topics. Thus, if you start multiple application with the same `application.id` they must be identical with regard to input topic they subscribe to and their processing logic. The application forms a consumer-group using the `application.id` as `group.id` and thus different partitions of the input topic(s) are assigned to different instances.

If you have different topic with the ***same*** logic, you can subscribe to ***all*** topic at once (in each instance you start). Scaling is still based on partitions though. (It's basically a "merge" of your input topics.)

If you want to scale via topics and/or have different processing logic, you must use different `application.id` for the different Kafka Streams applications.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation that states _"multiple application with the same application.id they must be identical with regard to input topic"_?

Comment: I am not sure. Note, that AK docs for Streams for v1.0 get reworked heavily atm -- comments/suggestions are welcome via mailing list.

Comment: so out of curiosity, say you have two instances of a service consuming from a topic with two partitions using the same application id. If one of those servers dies, can the one still running get messages from both partitions or do the messages on the partition that the down server was assigned to sit latent until that consumer is back up

Comment: If one instance fails, a rebalance will be triggered and the partition of the failed instance will be reassigned to the running one, that will process both after the rebalance. When the failed instances come back online, another rebalance will make sure that each instance will process one partition again (to ensure load balancing).